# Could not find com.google.firebase-core:17.0.1:

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, dart

I'm trying to implement Firebase in a project and when I try to build the app, I get this failure message:

> - What went wrong:
>     Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:preDebugBuild'.
>     Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
>     Could not find com.google.firebase-core:17.0.1:.
>      Required by:
>          project :app

My app/build.gradle dependencies are as follow:

```
dependencies {
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase-core:17.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

`apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'`

minSdkVersion21

targetSdkVersion28

My build.graddle is like this:

```
   buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

and finally pubspec.yaml dependencies are:

```
dependencies:



  firebase_core: ^0.4.0+6

  firebase_auth: ^0.11.1+10

  firebase_database: ^3.0.4

  http: ^0.12.0+2

  google_sign_in: ^4.0.4

  provider: ^3.0.0+1
```

Anyone can help me with this?

Comment: VPN? Could you be more specific on this? Why VPN?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure where you got this line:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase-core:17.0.1'
```

The Firebase core dependency looks like this, at the latest version:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.0.1'
```

I got this from the [getting started with Firebase on android](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup) docs.

Comment: bah, I had various error on the page, and I was playing with the code, so there were a moment when I leave this line like "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:" and then I have no idea how I missed to put 'firebase' when I get it back. thanks anyway!

Answer (score 2):

`com.google.firebase-core` has been [deprecated in October 2022](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android#2022-10-12). Instead of `firebase-core`, use `firebase-analytics` or `firebase-analytics-ktx`.